# using versionNumber plugin in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, version-numbering

**Context:**

We build our maven apps in which version number is injected by a `build.properties` file. Problem with this approach is that for every release, version number needs to be *bumped* manually.

---

Browsing online to fix this problem, i bumped into [version number plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin) which offers some cool ways to fix the issue.
For instance `-Dproject.version=${BUILD_YEAR}.${BUILDS_THIS_YEAR}` will solve the issue for me

**Problem**

I have issue setting up the values for the defined variables

Quoting from the doc:

> Initialization Values 
>   Before the build is started, the number of
>   builds this year / month / week / day can be specified on the command
>   line or via the job's plugin-configuration web-GUI. If they are
>   specified, then they will override whatever values are currently in
>   production. This allows you to migrate your version number from
>   another system to Jenkins if you choose to do so.
>
> Additionally, it is possible to automatically override the number of
>   builds this year / month / week / day with values taken from
>   environment-variables. Instead of just providing a simple number in
>   the form-fields of the job's plugin-configuration which overrides the
>   value for the next build (as described above), you can instead provide
>   an environment-variable whose value will be extracted and used during
>   the next builds. If it is not set or its value is not convertible to a
>   positive integer (without loosing precision), the value of the
>   previous build will be taken instead and increased by one (as is the
>   standard behavior).

In the last sentence, it says

```
If it is not set or its value is not convertible to a positive integer (without 
loosing precision), the value of the previous build will be taken instead 
and increased by one (as is the standard behavior)
```

So, going by this i built an jar with injected values of `BUILD_YEAR` and `BUILDS_THIS_YEAR`, worked as expected (jenkin says `Building my_app_2019.1-SNAPSHOT`). After that, i removed the variables assuming that they would be picked but unfortunatley jenkin says `Building my_app_${BUILD_YEAR}.${BUILDS_THIS_YEAR}-SNAPSHOT`.

There is no relevant doc around this or may be i have missed something totally obvious

**Question**

How do i ensure these `var` are injected correctly in my maven builds? or rather how do i populate the values using the plugin?

This is not a jenkins pipeline, its a simple jar builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missed setting up `Create a formatted version number` as below :

[image]

updated as per image above and changed command to `-Dproject.version=${VERSION_NUMBER}-SNAPSHOT`.... voila!!!!!